# C/C++ - printf acting weird

Tags: c++

My program needs to compute a bounding box from a vector a boundary objects, and min/max 3d vectors of this bounding box need to be used in a CUDA kernel.

To do so i get my bounding box in a c++ routine (`systemparticlesph.cpp`) :

```
void SystemParticleSPH::computeNeighborhood()
{
    //cellSize
    UniformGridParameters grid_params;
    grid_params.cellSize = sph_parameters.ParticleRadius;

    //bbox
    std::pair<glm::vec3, glm::vec3> bbox = CollisionObjectsContainer::getInstance()->getBBox();
    grid_params.min = std::get<0>(bbox);
    grid_params.max = std::get<1>(bbox);

    //works fine here ! 
    std::cout << "cpp cellSize " << grid_params.cellSize << std::endl;
    std::cout << "cpp min " << grid_params.min.x << " " << grid_params.min.y << " " << grid_params.min.z << std::endl;
    std::cout << "cpp max " << grid_params.max.x << " " << grid_params.max.y << " " << grid_params.max.z << std::endl;

    //cuda call
    computeNeighborsCuda(grid_params);
}
```

The results printed with cout are exactly what i expect according to the boundary objects i created :

```
cpp cellSize 0.02
cpp min -0.25 -0.25 -0.25
cpp max 0.25 0.25 0.25
```

I'm having a really hard time when i try to print the same exact data in the `computeNeighborsCuda(grid_params);` function located in `systemparticlessph.cu` :

```
void computeNeighborsCuda(UniformGridParameters grid_params)
{

    printf("cellsize %g min %g %g %g max %g %g %g\n",grid_params.cellSize, grid_params.min.x, grid_params.min.y, grid_params.min.z, grid_params.max.x, grid_params.max.y, grid_params.max.z );

    int numBlock =  m_dPos.size()/256 + 1;
    calcHashD<<<numBlock, 256>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&m_dGridParticleHash[0]), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&m_dGridParticleIndex[0]), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&m_dPos[0]), grid_params, m_dPos.size());
}
```

The results displayed (when i comment the 3 `cout`) should be the same but here is what i get :

`cellsize -0,25 min -0,25 -0,25 0,25 max 0,25 0,25 -7168,19`

It looks like there is some offset making the whole thing wrong : `cellSize` has the value of `min.x`, while `max.z` has an arbitrary value.

Note that the problem is exactly the same when i call `printf` from the CUDA kernel.

Also note that it is getting worse when i display both with cout and printf at the same time :

```
cpp cellSize 0.02
cpp min -0.25 -0.25 -0.25
cpp max 0.25 0.25 0.25
cellsize -1,79826e+36 min 0 1,21731e-37 0 max 1,21731e-37 0 1,21731e-37
```

Do you have any idea of to get the same result in the C function (and kernel) ?

Thanks in advance, this is really giving me a hard time.

Mathias

## Edit :

Passing a reference instead of a copy of the structure, everything works perfectly fine.

Still, i have no idea why it does not work with a copy of the structure.

Comment: what does UB mean ?

Comment: Please try to replace %g with %f.

Comment: I already did, the results are the same, with some more decimals : ```cellsize -0,250000 min -0,250000 -0,250000 0,250000 max 0,250000 0,250000 -350888301291506888700118171648,000000```

Comment: [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: What are the types of the arguments?

Comment: cellSize is a ```float```, min and max are both ```glm::vec3``` from glm library

Comment: my guess would be stack corruption elsewhere in your program.  If that is the case, passing the structure by reference is just hiding the actual issue, and it will likely pop up somewhere else in your code as confusing behavior there too.  For questions like this ("why isn't this code working") SO expects you to provide an [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to make your own struct with simple variables and copy the exact data you want to show from the c++ program into the CUDA function.